# Delete file returned by "mpc search" with single command

Tags: command-line, terminal, command, mpd

using the **mpc search command** I can find a the filename of a song like so:

```
mpc search title 'Two Weeks'
```

The output would look like this: `Grizzly Bear - Two Weeks.mp3`

Since I also know the location of the mp3 (MPD Music directory), I know how I could delete the file with another command. But I want to have a one-line command that finds and deletes a music file in my MPD directory.

Comment: perhaps something as simple as: `rm "/path/to/MPD/Music/directory/$(mpc search title 'Two Weeks')"` ?

Comment: this could be a little tricky. how would you handle more than 1 results? Would you be willing to delete all the returned results?

Comment: @nass There is also a mpc command called "mpc find", it returns only one result, and only when you query result matches exactly with what you searched for. As I already know a parameter for each item I would search for, I would probably use that command. Although if I want to delete multiple items that, for example are in the same album, I'd have to use `mpc search`. But yes I would have to be careful with that.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yess thank you, that did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption that only one filename comes back, you can use something like:

```
rm "/path/to/MPD/Music/directory/$(mpc search title 'Two Weeks')"
```

If there are multiple results, this will break.